# create a pop up aspx page and by the close button that would close..?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want To Create A aspx pop up Page on a button and then in that pop up a close button should be there and by that close button pop up would be closed.

Comment: what do you want to show on the popup?

Answer (score 0):

Create a Div with ID 'popUpDiv' and put all your required controls in it.

and your click button

```
<asp:Button onclick="popup('popUpDiv')" ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Click to Close CSS Pop Up" />
```

Try [DEMO](http://www.pat-burt.com/csspopup.html) here

use this [JS file](http://www.pat-burt.com/csspopup.js)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [jQueryUI's Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) instead of fiddling around with manual positioning and event handling. Then you can use:

```
$('#somediv').dialog();
```